# C#, WPF ComboBox with two items inside

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have combo box which displays room numbers. Now i want to show room numbers and room types like this

```
102 Suite Double
305 Standard Single
```

and so on.
I done this but problem is that i cannot get only room number. Can anyone advice me something?

Comment: What is your problem? I don't understand the text under the code sample.

Comment: You'll also need to show us what you've done.

Comment: Create a class Room, add 2 fields Number and RoomType, implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Put all your Rooms into your List and bind it to ItemsSource of your ComboBox. Create an ItemTemplate for your ComboBox with 2 Textblock and Bindings like {Binding Number}. Now if the user selects a Room the property SelectedItem on your Combobox contains the Room class instance of the selected room, where you can retrieve via your properties the number. A better explanation is possible, if your question would be better. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have two columns in the DataSource called: `RoomNumberAndName` and `RoomNumber` (id) you just need this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbData" ItemsSource="{Binding DpData}"
              DisplayMemberPath="RoomNumberAndName"
              SelectedValuePath="RoomNumber" />
```

Comment: You copied a line from one of my answers o.O

Comment: yup actually I was going to link it as duplicate then lost the link, too many browser tabs open. can you do it?